# How can I clamp the transform to a range?

Tags: unity, validation

I am trying to create a level editor in Unity.  When the position of an object is changed, I want that object to have its X and Y positions clamped between 1 and 10.  So if the position is changed to 15, it will snap back to 10; and if the position is changed to -5, it will snap back to 1.

I have tried using the OnValidate() method, but without success.  It snaps everything correctly when I reload the script (make a change to the script and reopen Unity), but it will not snap it on the fly.

```
void OnValidate(){
    float newX = Mathf.Clamp(child.position.x, 1, 10);
    float newY = Mathf.Clamp(child.position.y, 1, 10);
    transform.localPosition = new Vector2(newX, newY);
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: @Robert, that will yield a random number between those two values, which is not the desired behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnValidate is only called when the [script is loaded or a value is changed in the inspector](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) (Called in the editor only).

You're probably looking for `Update()`

```
void Update(){
    float newX = Mathf.Clamp(child.position.x, 1, 10);
    float newY = Mathf.Clamp(child.position.y, 1, 10);
    transform.localPosition = new Vector2(newX, newY);
}
```

There is a way to get this method to execute in the editor, according to [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/update-in-editor-script.52553/) which is [ExecuteInEditMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html).

> Makes a script execute in edit mode.
>
> By default, script components are only executed in play mode. By adding this attribute, each script component will also have its callback functions executed while the Editor is not in playmode.
>
> - Update is only called when something in the scene changed.

This should get the behavior you desire, by adding `[ExecuteInEditMode]` (C#) or `@script ExecuteInEditMode()` (JS) to the top of your class file.

Alternatively, you can use [OnDrawGizmos()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) which is called when the object is selected in the scene view.  Please note:

> This function does not get called if the component is collapsed in the inspector. Use OnDrawGizmosSelected to draw gizmos when the game object is selected.

This means that if your script is collapsed in the inspector, this method won't be called.

Comment: The position is where I want it.  Update will only work during runtime.  I want this to be updated in the editor.  I change the transform value in the inspector, yet it does not update.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear in your question.  I'll assume that your method is correct (I can't imagine how that does what you want it to do, but if you say it does, then it does).  The problem is that `OnValidate()` only triggers when a value associated *with that script* is changed.  Modifying a different component or using the transform handles won't trigger it.

Comment: That sounds accurate, thanks.  Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: @Evorlor you can either add the [ExecuteInEditMode attribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) to your class, which will make Draco18s's suggested use of Update work, or use a method that's normally called in-editor like [OnDrawGizmos](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html)

Comment: Was just adding that to my answer via edit, @DMGregory :)

Comment: @Evorlor I was just doing the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` thing, which I had found and looked up while DMGregory was commenting.  I will add `OnDrawGizmos` as well.